# error : storage class specified for parameter

Tags: c, linux

I have a C code written. When I compile it on Linux then in the header file it says the 
following error:   `storage class specified for parameter i32 , i8`   and so on

```
typedef int i32;

typedef char    i8;
```

Comment: You'll need to show a bit more code.

Comment: I got this eror when I was daydreaming and declared a memebr function as `extern` in the class definition (slides off sheepishly, cheeks aflame)

Answer (score 356, accepted):

Chances are you've forgotten a semicolon in a header file someplace.  Make sure each line ends in `;`

Comment: This. The error likely gets reported in some source code file you are sure you didn't touch—but that file happens to include the header file which has the syntax error.

Comment: it does not need to be a semicolon. It can also be a curly bracket { lost in the lost that needs to be removed

Comment: This was also the case for me, but I don't understand why a missing semi-colon in a headre fiel would generate an error message about storage classes.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same experience. The problem was at the function prototype declaration in the header file where a semicolon was missing at the end of function declaration.

The function was indicated in the compilation logs as `In function ...`  just before the error snippet.

Answer (score 22):

You have some code somewhere, probably indicated in the full text of the error message, that does something like this:

```
void function(static int foo)
```

The `static` is not allowed there. It could also be another storage class, like `register` or `extern`.

Answer (score 7):

I incurred this same error once. The solution was to browse around files and look for pending statements (like a non-closed parenthesis, or a missing semicolon.) Usually it's really a trivial error, but the compiler complains.

The bad news is that it doesn't always complain at the right line (or even in the right file!) The good news is that in these cases it says something useful like:

```
WRONGFILE.h: In function ‘FUNCTION_OF_ANOTHER_FILE_WRT_WRONG_FILE’"
WRONGFILE:line:col: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘param’ before.
```

Go and check in that other reported file.

Answer (score 2):

To add up on `;`: another case can be a missing `)` in a function pointer declaration:

```
extern void init_callbacks(void (*init)(), void (*end());
```

(missing closing parenthesis after `*end`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vim editor, you can easily find missing semicolon by typing:

```
/[^;]\s*$
```

...and then jump up/down (with N/n), until problematic line is found.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, while error was missing the storage class name in static assignment. E.g.:

```
.h:
class MyClass {
   static const int something;
}

.cpp:
const int something = 1; // returns error
const int MyClass::something = 1; // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

As Mawg pointed out in a comment, declaring a class member function as `extern` can cause similar issues.