# How can I use a global variable in C++?

Tags: c++, c, qt, qml, blackberry-10

I'm developping a Blackberry 10 mobile app. using the momentics IDE (BB Native SDK).

In my application, I want to use global variables that will be shared by many classes.

I tried the code below like described in this [link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/), but when I add the ***extern*** instruction before the declaration of the variable "**g_nValue*** " in the ".h" file, it returns the error **"storage class specified for 'g_nValue'"**

*/ global.cpp:

```
// declaration of g_nValue
int g_nValue = 5;
```

*/ global.h:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H // header guards
#define GLOBAL_H

// extern tells the compiler this variable is declared elsewhere
extern int g_nValue;

#endif
```

Any one have an idea on this? I searched a lot and they all said that the ***extern*** instruction should not cause any trouble.

Comment: The code looks correct. Googling about this error, it probably looks like [you have a syntax error elsewhere in the file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17381614/1600898).

Comment: Is that your whole `global.h` file?  What is included just before `global.h` is included?  I suspect there's a missing semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to extern are static variables inside a class:

```
//.h
struct Globals
{
    static int g_global_var;
};

//.cpp
int Globals::g_global_var = 0;

//usage:
Globals::g_global_var;
```

Comment: the static members are not global in C++,  each .cpp file will has its own copy of the variable like explained in this [forum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349877/static-global-variables-in-c) instead of using the global variable

Comment: @user2072762 incorrect. `static` at namespace scope is different to `static` at class scope.

Comment: As Simple says. I can't remember I ever encountered a valid use case for `extern` in a modern C++ codebase.

Answer (score 1):

the `extern` qualifier only tells the compiler, "this symbol is defined in a different source file" - so the symbol exists, it's safe to use it.  You will get a linking error if you actually "lie" about it and don't define the symbol - but that's a different story.

There does not seam to be any problem with the code you showed us.
But here is a [link](http://quantlabs.net/blog/2010/05/c-storage-classes-and-qualifiers-like-auto-extern-register-volatile-const-mutable/) which might help you get a better idea...

Comment: Perhaps you could make a small 'recap' of what the link contains of info - we do not know how long the link will work, and your answer is connected to information inside this other website

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare the variable `exteren` in the compilation unit it's defined in.  You only declare it `extern` (and *don't* define it) if you want to use it in other `.cpp` files (compilation units).

Comment: Sorry !! but I didn't understand your answer. Can you explain more ?

Comment: That is exactly what the OP is doing: *declaring* the variable with use of `extern` (in the header), and *defining* it without `extern`.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have an `extern` declaration for a variable in the same translation unit as the definition for the variable. In fact, I think it's a good practice to have the file that defines the variable also include the header that declares it `extern` so you can be sure the type in the header's declaration matches with the actual definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Maybe the you have an error elsewhere. Maybe there is a semicolon (;) missing in a line before `extern int g_nValue`.